# Generic typing doesn't play well with StatefulWidget & Function

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have the following bit of code, which at first, seems like it should work -

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    GenericWidget<int>(
      value: 69,
      render: (BuildContext context, int value) {
        return Text("$value");
      },
    ),
  );
}

class GenericWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T value;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) render;

  const GenericWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.render,
    @required this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GenericWidgetState<T> createState() => _GenericWidgetState();
}

class _GenericWidgetState<T> extends State<GenericWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.render(context, widget.value);
  }
}
```

The reasoning behind having `T`, is that a `GenericWidget` is capable of rending data of generic type.

But flutter doesn't seem to understand what I'm trying to achieve here -

```
I/flutter (24311): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (24311): The following _TypeError was thrown building GenericWidget<int>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (24311): _GenericWidgetState<int>#f80f3):
I/flutter (24311): type '(BuildContext, int) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, dynamic) => Widget'
I/flutter (24311): 
I/flutter (24311): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (24311):   GenericWidget<int> file:///Users/dev/FlutterProjects/dara-client/pad.dart:5:5
I/flutter (24311): 
I/flutter (24311): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (24311): #0      _GenericWidgetState.build (file:///Users/dev/FlutterProjects/dara-client/pad.dart:31:19)
I/flutter (24311): #1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
I/flutter (24311): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
I/flutter (24311): #3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
I/flutter (24311): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
I/flutter (24311): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
I/flutter (24311): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
I/flutter (24311): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
I/flutter (24311): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
I/flutter (24311): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
I/flutter (24311): #10     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1252:16)
I/flutter (24311): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1223:5)
I/flutter (24311): #12     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1165:17)
I/flutter (24311): #13     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2683:19)
I/flutter (24311): #14     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1164:13)
I/flutter (24311): #15     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:974:7)
I/flutter (24311): #16     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:955:7)
I/flutter (24311): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (24311): 
I/flutter (24311): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Is there a recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like the compiler is not built to resolve generics "all the way down", for the special case of Function arguments.

The constructor to `_GenericWidgetState()` doesn't have the information about the resolved type (`int`) when it's initialized, so dart just resolves the type to be `dynamic` for the state instance.

This hypothesis can be verified easily -

```
main() {
  Widget widget = Widget<int>((int value) {});

  // (int) => Null
  widget.reveal();

  // Exception: type '(int) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'
  widget.state.reveal();
}

class Widget<T> {
  final void Function(T) value;

  State<T> state;

  Widget(this.value) {
    state = State<T>();
    state.widget = this;
  }

  void reveal() {
    print(value.runtimeType);
  }
}

class State<T> {
  Widget widget;

  void reveal() {
    print(widget.value.runtimeType);
  }
}
```

To fix this, we just need to force-resolve the exact type of `T` -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    GenericWidget(
      value: 69,
      render: (BuildContext context, int value) {
        return Text("$value");
      },
    ),
  );
}

class GenericWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T value;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) render;

  const GenericWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.render,
    @required this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GenericWidgetState<T> createState() => _GenericWidgetState(render);
}

class _GenericWidgetState<T> extends State<GenericWidget> {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) render;

  _GenericWidgetState(this.render);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return render(context, widget.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just missed the generic type parameter `T`, on the State - `class _GenericWidgetState<T> extends State<GenericWidget<T>>`

This works great.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    GenericWidget<int>(
      value: 69,
      render: (BuildContext context, int value) {
        return Text("$value");
      },
    ),
  );
}

class GenericWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T value;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) render;

  const GenericWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.render,
    @required this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GenericWidgetState<T> createState() => _GenericWidgetState();
}

class _GenericWidgetState<T> extends State<GenericWidget<T>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.render(context, widget.value);
  }
}
```